# Searching by fragments if values are string type but search by and entire if value is int

Tags: c#, linq, mvvm

I decided to create a simple MVVM application in C#. I have a collection of users. I can edit them, add, remove, update and search. And with this last option I have a problem. Below is a portion of problematic code:

```
var Usersview = new ObservableCollection<User>
                (from item in Users
                 where (
                Convert.ToString(item.UserId) == (Names[0])
                && item.FirstName.Contains(Names[1])
                && item.LastName.Contains(Names[2])
                && item.City.Contains(Names[3])
                && item.State.Contains(Names[4])
                && item.Country.Contains(Names[5]))
                select item);
```

**Names** is my array of values which can be searched.
Names can be empty.
Only UserID is int, rest are string.

What I want to achieve is searching by fragments of string type Names, but if a UserID value is set, a program has to search by entire int (not its fragment). If Names[0] is string.Empty a program does not search anything. Could you help me? But remember. These are my first steps with MVVM and Linq. So please be forgiving.

Comment: So what you want is: Search  by user id pr if empty then by everything else?

Comment: If so, you could create something like `((Convert.ToString(item.UserId) != "" && Convert.ToString(item.UserId) == Name) || ( item.FirstName && item.SecondName && ..))`

Comment: Searching by UserID is not Priamary. Simple Scenarios: I set Firstname = "Ad". My program finds all records with names like: Adrian, Adik, Ador (fictive names :) . I set number 7 I want to find only record with this number, not with 77,777,7777 etc.

Comment: Yes, it does :)

Comment: What i meant in my statement is: Where :    userID is not empty and is equal, if these are not true search users that item.firstName contains searched firstName etc..

Comment: Ther is one issue with your statement. If i set for example number 7 and set FirstName = "Ad" the porgram finds me my record 7 + records with this name. If a set number the program should find only one record. :( or nothing if number does not contain searched FirstName.

Comment: Oh ok, then use :   `userID == searchedID || ( userID == "" && item.FirstName ... )`

Comment: It searches only when i set UserID :(  var Usersview = new ObservableCollection<User>
                (from item in Users
                 where (
                (Convert.ToString(item.UserId) == (Names[0])
                || (Convert.ToString(item.UserId) == ""
                && (item.FirstName.Contains(Names[1])
                && item.LastName.Contains(Names[2])
                && item.City.Contains(Names[3])
                && item.State.Contains(Names[4])
                && item.Country.Contains(Names[5])))))
                select item);

Comment: What is your userID if it's empty? Is it ""?

Comment: It is a string.Empty

Comment: Then instead of == "" use String.IsNullOrEmpty(userId)

Comment: Why do you call a member of `Users` an `item`? Why not `from user in Users`? Why are your search criteria in an array called `Names`? That doesn't seem to be what they are.

Comment: You say " If Names[0] is string.Empty a program does not search anything" but that makes no sense in conjunction with "if a UserID value is set". Are there records that have no `UserID` value? Or did you mean if `Names[0] is set, in which case it would "not search anything"? I would suggest you need to rewrite your question.

Comment: I wrote these are my first steps in linq ☺. I thought a word item is a standard in c# like "I" before interface names. My search criteria is in array Names because... I forgot to rename array. During implementation I encountered a problem which is described here: http://www.shujaat.net/2011/01/updatesourcetrigger-explicit-for-mvvm.html?m=1

Comment: Every single record has all values. Each column in my record cannot be null. But I don't have to fill each textbox to search records. So, Names (my search criteria) can be empty or null.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Presumably, all your search fields don't have to be filled in for the search. Also, you shouldn't convert an `int` to a `string` to compare equality. Renaming your range variable and search criteria to be more meaningful, I get:

```
var Usersview = new ObservableCollection<User>
                (from user in Users
                 where
                     (String.IsNullOrEmpty(searchCriteria[0]) || Convert.ToInt32(searchCriteria[0]) == user.UserId) &&
                     (String.IsNullOrEmpty(searchCriteria[1]) || user.FirstName.Contains(searchCriteria[1])) &&
                     (String.IsNullOrEmpty(searchCriteria[2]) || user.LastName.Contains(searchCriteria[2]) &&
                     (String.IsNullOrEmpty(searchCriteria[3]) || user.City.Contains(searchCriteria[3])) &&
                     (String.IsNullOrEmpty(searchCriteria[4]) || user.State.Contains(searchCriteria[4])) &&
                     (String.IsNullOrEmpty(searchCriteria[5]) || user.Country.Contains(searchCriteria[5]))
                select user);
```

Comment: I afk now but I'll check your solution when I return from holidays☺  But it seems it is okay.